# Setting Width of Textbox according to maxlenth

Tags: c#, winforms

I am using winforms application and i want to set that width of textbox which will show characters till max length,in short something like **width = maxlength**.Any predefined property is there? or we have to calculate it manually?

//I am looking for this type of logic

```
  private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //sample project
        textBox2.Width = textBox2.MaxLength;
        textBox3.Width = textBox3.MaxLength;
        textBox4.Width = textBox4.MaxLength;
    }
```

Comment: Please show your work. What have you tried? What doesn't work for you? Have you even had a look at the documentation; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox(v=vs.110).aspx ?

Comment: Unit mismatch: Width is in Pixels, MaxLength in characters. So you need to measure the Font using e.g. Graphics.MeasureString.. Works best for fixed Fonts like Consolas.

Comment: yes I came across MeasureString ,but it requires text as first parameter.I want to set the size at initial stage only..

Comment: @TaW's comment should probably be posted as an answer, but just to expand upon it, if you want the textbox to resize dynamically as you're typing, you'll need to use the TextChanged event on your textbox to resize it.

Comment: @AdrianoSantros You don't know what width you will need until you know what text is going in the box. You can probably find the widest character in the font being used and use that as a worst case. (although you can't be sure what font is being used by the user, unless you force use of a specific font - which I'd avoid at all costs).

Comment: @Bryan It is sure that What data is going to filled by user is not more than 25 character.Also I am using default font for text box.So I was expecting that text box length will be set precisely as per max length

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a Unit Mismatch: Width is in Pixels, MaxLength in characters.

So you need to measure the Font using e.g. Graphics.MeasureString.. Works best for fixed Fonts like Consolas.

You can measure the font e.g. like this, using 'x' as a medium width letter:

```
using (Graphics G = textBox2.CreateGraphics())
   textBox2.Width = (int) (textBox2.MaxLength * 
                           G.MeasureString("x", textBox2.Font).Width);
```

There are other Font measurement methods like `TextRenderer.MeasureText` you could use; also both methods have [options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.textformatflags%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to fine tune the measurement. The default above will include some leeway.

If you use a fixed Font the width will be OK, if you don't you'll need to decide whether you'd rather be on the safe side (use "W" or "M" to measure) or not. "X" is a likely compromise. Or you could adapt dynamically in the e.g. the TextChanged event..

Comment: "i" will be pretty thin for most fonts, but whatever works for you is fine with me..BTW: In typography and also in HTML there are space characters of varying widths, both thinner "thin-space"  than a normal space and thicker e.g. the "en-space" or the "em-space"..

Answer (score 0):

Use the Anchor property to define how a control is automatically resized as its parent control is resized
Anchoring a control to its parent control ensures that the anchored edges remain in the same position relative to the edges of the parent control when the parent control is resized.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
textbox1.MaxLength = 0//The default value is 0, which indicates no limit;
```

Refer this msdn link for more info:

[msdn link for textbox maxlength](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.maxlength(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Nope I want to set size of textbox according to max length. Max length may be 10,25 or 35